# What are the prospects of a Math Master student applying to Finance PhD programs?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

> - What are the prospects of a Math Master student applying to top tier Finance PhD program?

So here's a little bit of my background.

I'm currently in my second year of my Mathematics master degree, applying to Finance PhD programs. The top tier Universities are definitely what I'm aiming for. What are my prospects?

Aspects where I felt like I am disadvantaged compared to other Finance PhD applicants:

> - I have not taken a lot of Finance/Econ course
> - I have little research experience compare to other applicants
> - Admission commitee might question my determination to go into the field of Finance

Aspects where I have outstanding performance/other information:

> - I have a background of Master in Math, which I assume most applicants don't
> - I have taken plenty of courses in applied math, including real analysis (I'm currently the grader for the  first year graduate real analysis class)
> - I graduated Summa Cum Laude with a 4.0 GPA. I am still keeping the GPA in my graduate courses so far.
> - General GRE scores 
>     -Quantitative: 170/170(98% below)
>     -Verbal: 156/170(71% below)
>     -Writing: 3.5/6 (38% below)
> - Math GRE scores: 860/980 (89% below)

I would very much appreciate if someone in the Finance/Econ academia (graduate student/Professors) can give me some advice. Besides my odds of getting accepted,

> - What are others things I can do to improve my chances of getting into the top schools?

Comment: _one of them offer me the opportunity to do research with him_ Do you think you'll get a good recommendation letter from him? Do you think you'll get  more recommendation letters from other Finance professors as well? Would you have good recommendations letters from Math professors? What's the rank of your current masters program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the admissions process work for US Ph.D. programs, particularly for weak or borderline students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-us-ph-d-programs-particularly-for-wea)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't do personalized assessments of chances of admissions here. See "Can I ask about my specific situation?" in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Admissions for PhD programs at top-tier schools is hyper competitive, and I would imagine it to be even more for finance and economy. Admissions there get huge pools of applicants and they are spoiled in their choices. Applicants would come with these perfect GPA and GRE scores and crafted portfolios from top-tier undergrad programs and so on.

I would say, though, that you can apply and see. **But** do not limit yourself with top tier universities! You can always find 2nd-tier ones with fantastic research groups in some specific areas that might be of your interest. Do NOT choose where you want to do PhD solely based on the reputation of the university. There is more to it than that, you have to see the research group and their reputation and what journals/conferences they publish in, etc...

Also, here is a link for you to read. You might find it to be such a treat.
http://noahpinionblog.blogspot.com/2013/05/if-you-get-phd-get-economics-phd.html